# Fetching mysql records of current year in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I need to fetch records within interval of an year in cakephp. I tried with the following query by `time` condition is not working.

`$accept = $this->AssignListing->find('all',array('conditions' => array('AssignListing.writer_id' => $writer,'AssignListing.status' => 1, 'AssignListing.date_added > NOW( ) - INTERVAL 1 YEAR')));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you.

```
$accept = $this->AssignListing->find('all',array('conditions' => array('AssignListing.writer_id' => $writer,'AssignListing.status' => 1, 'AssignListing.date_added >=' => 'DATE_ADD(NOW( ), INTERVAL -1 YEAR')));
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it easier in this case to just:

```
$str_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 Year'));

$accept = $this->AssignListing->find('all',array('conditions' => array(
'AssignListing.writer_id' => $writer,
'AssignListing.status' => 1, 
'AssignListing.date_added >' => $str_time)));
```

And compare that value? When possible, do the calcuation once in php and parse it instead of in MySQL.

[**strtotime()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)
[**date()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do the trick,

```
$accept = $this->AssignListing->find('all',array('conditions' => array(
'AssignListing.writer_id' => $writer,
'AssignListing.status' => 1, 
array('AssignListing.date_added BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array(date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-1 Year")), date('Y-m-d'))))));
```